# How can I combine different AndroidManifest.xml files to use different plugins/libraries?

Tags: android, android-manifest

I'm making a Unity application for Android and I'm using *Vuforia* and *Easy Code Scanner*. Their Unity packages both come with iOS and Android compiled libraries. For the Android version of the libraries, both of them have a proper AndroidManifest.xml file. As far as I know, only one manifest per app is allowed, but to be able to use both of them I need in some way to combine them.

Having the plugins in the proper place but using just one manifest, will generate an *activity not found exception*.

I tried to combine the 2 xml files by myself but I failed. Can you please give me some hints in how to perform this action?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by the [Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html) here's the general scheme.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest>

    <uses-permission />
    <permission />
    <permission-tree />
    <permission-group />
    <instrumentation />
    <uses-sdk />
    <uses-configuration />  
    <uses-feature />  
    <supports-screens />  
    <compatible-screens />  
    <supports-gl-texture />  

    <application>

        <activity>
            <intent-filter>
                <action />
                <category />
                <data />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data />
        </activity>

        <activity-alias>
            <intent-filter> . . . </intent-filter>
            <meta-data />
        </activity-alias>

        <service>
            <intent-filter> . . . </intent-filter>
            <meta-data/>
        </service>

        <receiver>
            <intent-filter> . . . </intent-filter>
            <meta-data />
        </receiver>

        <provider>
            <grant-uri-permission />
            <meta-data />
            <path-permission />
        </provider>

        <uses-library />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Well... in my case the same application was defined 2 times but with different configurations. What I did is to give priority to *QCAR*. I have merged the configurations by adding everything that were missed in the **application** defined for *Vuforia*.
After that I copied all the activities from both the manifests and past them into the **application**. You should check that every **activity** is defined only once: if the same **activity** is defined in both the manifests, just proceed to merge them as done for the **application**.

Hope those hints could be useful for someone else  :)